# Display my app in Hebrew (or other languages)?

Tags: android, localization

My company makes industrial manufacturing products where Android devices are used on the factory floor as remote controls for the machinery.  We program and ship the Android devices with our products and they consist of Samsung handheld devices running 2.35 or 2.36, or tablets running various version of 4.x.

Our international business is growing and we have customers in Israel, Russia, and various Asian countries that would like the app to display in their local language.  We'd like to start with Hebrew.

The customers only have access to our app -  they don't use the rest of the device.  We'd like the buttons and labels in our app to display in Hebrew, including right-to-left reading.   We don't care if the keyboard comes up in Hebrew - it's not important for our app - and we'd prefer that the REST of the device, especially Settings, stay in English for our field service people.

I know I need to create unique strings and themes in Resources, but where do I get a Hebrew language glyphs or fonts, how do I enforce right-to-left display, and is there a way to just make our app display in Hebrew without making the entire device switch over (because I'm afraid we wouldn't be able to figure out how to switch it back!)

Comment: Change localization on start of your app programmatically and set back to english after your work is done or you exit the application.

Comment: @Ravi Bhatt:I didn't know I could do that, thank you!    Now, on to the glyph/font/right-left-display part of the question . . .

Comment: If you set localization, the left-right or any other localization related changes happen automatically. Try it.